# The force on loose end of a membrane

Tags: forces, waves, continuum-mechanics

If I have a membrane that has one loose end, does it mean that the tension on that end is equal to zero and because of that the the force on that end is also equal to zero?

[image]

Comment: What about the sides of the membrane?

Comment: It is given that all the other three sides are fixed. Meaning $z(0,y)=z(x,0)=z(x,b)=z(a,y)=0$

Comment: Not to sure what z means in your comment--but answered anyway  :).

Comment: Is this sheet static - not moving. You mention wave equation in your comments. So is z the height of the sheet above the xy-plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I have a membrane that has one loose end, does it mean that the
>   tension on that end is equal to zero and because of that the the force
>   on that end is also equal to zero?

Yes, if that end is completely loose.  If it is stretched from side to side by tension at the corners--then no.  The way to analyze this would be to use a free body diagram.

See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_body_diagram

Comment: By $z$ I meant the wave equation in membrane. In class we learned that if three out of four sides of the membrane are held still then the force on each element of mass on the side that is loose is zero. Meaning:$Z(x=0,y,t)=Z(x=L,y,t)=Z(x,y=0,t)=0 $ and $\frac{ \partial Z(x,y,t) }{\partial y}|_{y=L}=0 $. I can’t understand why.

Comment: If you conceptually break the membrane into small squares and do the free-body diagram on each square, with the idea that there is a force on each edge, then the definition of a loose edge is that there is zero force on that edge. If the sheet is in static equilibrium, then the forces on the two sides adjacent to the free edge will be angled up to counteract the force on the side opposite. This leads to that square - taken as a free-body - to have zero acceleration , even though there is a force on the far edge and not on the free edge.

Comment: @ violettagold Re "then the force on each element of mass on the side that is loose is zero"  I think that is the definition of 'loose'.

Comment: Thank you I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you stretch a stretchy square rubber sheet out so that the left and right edges are kept straight and parallel, but the top and bottom are otherwise unconstrained, then the top and botton edges will curve inward until the tension along the edge of the sheet is angled enough to counteract the vertical contraction due to the horizontal elongation.

If the sheet itself cannot stretch enough, there is a tendency to get a "flappy" edge, which would indicate zero tension, which is why shade-sails these days are typically not square, but have edges that curve inward so the whole sail is under tension when pulled tight from the corners.

Comment: Hi, I meant that three sides of the membrane are held still and one is lose. $Z(x=0,y,t)=Z(x=L,y,t)=Z(x,y=0,t)=0 $ when z is the wave equation of the membrane.